how to use a formula express this ？
Given two fixed points, the line connecting the two points is initially a straight line. Given a parameter t $\in$[0,1], when  gradually changes from 0 to 1, the line connecting the two points will change as follows:
t = 0
enter image description here
t = 0.2
enter image description here
t = 0.6
enter image description here
t = 0.8
enter image description here
t = 1
enter image description here
when t = 1, the line looks like semicircle.
I know there may be many approximate equations to describe this process. I hope that the above process can be expressed approximately, without the need for exact,just give one of it.

You question is very vague. Technically there can be infinitely many family of curves that have that kind of behaviour, Can you be more specific? Where is the question from? Where did you get the curves from and what are the requirements?

There are infinitely many solutions to your requirement. Your description is unclear but I'll assume that it's symmetrical, then one such solution is simply a circular arc $A(t)$ that goes through points $p_0$, $p_1$. Let $q(t)$ be the intersection between $A(t)$ and the bisector of $p_0p_1$. Assume that $p_0 = (-d,0)$ and $p_1 = (d,0)$, then the bisector of $p_0p_1$ is the $y$ axis. You can easily find that $q(0) = (0,0)$ and $q(1) = (d,0)$. Therefore you can assume the interpolation $q(t) = (td,0)$. The radius of the circula arc satisfies the following equation
$$td = R - \sqrt{R^2-d^2}$$
Solving this gives $R = \dfrac{t^2+1}{2t} d$.
The center of the circular arc is then $(0,td-R) = \left(0,\dfrac{t^2-1}{2t}d\right)$
The formula for the circle would be
$$x^2 + \left(y - \frac{t^2-1}{2t}d\right)^2 = \frac{(t^2+1)^2}{4t^2}d^2$$
Finally we derive the equation for the circular arc:
$$A(t): y = \frac{t^2-1}{2t}d + \sqrt{\frac{(t^2+1)^2}{4t^2}d^2 - x^2}$$
for $-d \leq x \leq d$ and $0 < t \leq 1$. To extend the equation to $t = 0$ we can use the conjugation $a + \sqrt{b} = \frac{a^2-b}{a-\sqrt{b}}$
$$A(t): y = \frac{2t(x^2 - d^2)}{(t^2-1)d - \sqrt{(t^2+1)^2d^2-4x^2t^2}}$$

I can give you a very simple solution: just take the perpendicular bisector (which crosses the center of your line segment), and use that parameter $t$ as a basis for putting the center of your newly created arc on a circle, something like:

The point $A$ is determined by its distance to $C$, as follows:
$$d(A,C) = \frac{1-t}{t}$$
$t=1$: the distance is zero, and you get half a circle.
$t=0$: the distance is infinite and you get the line segment.
